# extjs, Slideout animation doesnot work when I put a duration on it

Tags: extjs

This code below is good with default animation. But it's too fast.

```
pnlDataInput.el.slideIn('t');
```

So I give it a custom duration. And it never animation with any duration value. It just show up.

```
pnlDataInput.el.slideIn('t', {
            duration: 4
        });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either the duration may be in milliseconds:

```
pnlDataInput.el.slideIn('t', {
        duration: 4000
    });
```

Or you may need an easing option:

```
pnlDataInput.el.slideIn('t', {
        easing: 'easeOut',
        duration: 4
    });
```

Comment: It is milliseconds. In doc, their write seconds. So confused. Btw thank you.

Comment: Yeah, I was confused when I looked it up.  Apparently general animations have a seconds argument but this specific one has ms.  Seems like bad practice to me, but I bet there's some obscure reason for it that didn't get documented.